# Has anyone used the ant task for Cobertura to exclude annotated java classes?

Tags: cobertura

Apparently earlier this year Cobertura added "IgnoreMethodAnnotation" to their latest code base.   I've been trying to get this to work, and thanks to the lack of documentation on their site have no idea how to get their ant task to do this.  Has anyone used this new feature they added?   What I have below runs but the reports all still have the class that is annotated in the report.

Sample of my ant task I've tried:

```
<cobertura-instrument todir="build/instrumented" ignoreTrivial="true">
<classpath >
<path refid="classpath"/>
</classpath>

<ignoreMethodAnnotation annotationName="ExcludeFromCoverage"/>
```

Comment: I just created an issue at the github cobertura repository: https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/issues/33 which has a milestone release of later next week.

Comment: Thanks, so you've confirmed that it isn't working?

Comment: I am not sure. If you look at http://bit.ly/1aq70hc at the InstrumentTask.java which is what ant uses, it looks like there should be no issues with what you wrote. I will keep investigating this further and I will be upgrading the documentation (could use a restructure). I tested this and it does work via command line and though maven. There is a new release scheduled for sometime this Friday.

Comment: So after a few days of investigating I figured out that the annotationName requires package and the annotation name (name.of.package.ExcludeFromCoverage). Also I figured out that the annotations do not work if it's at the class level, they need to be over each method. I will also be updating the documentation with this new information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see documentation for
[Ignore Trivial](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/wiki/Ant-Task-Reference#ignore-trivial) and
[Ignore Method Annotation](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/wiki/Ant-Task-Reference#ignore-method-annotation)